# Multiple ports on Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have an apache2 server on Ubuntu 14.04 with 2 sites on different ports:
site1.domain.com -> Port 80
site2.domain.com -> Port 8888

```
http://site1.domain.com -> OK
http://site2.domain.com:8888 -> OK
http://site1.domain.com:8888 -> Also OK
```

I wonder site1 only on port 80 and site2 only on port 8888.

My: ports.conf are:

```
Listen 8888 

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
   Listen 443
</IfModule>
Listen 80
```

The site1 has:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

And the site2 has:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
```

TIA

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but did you add the NameVirtualHost option in your config?

Comment: posting your full config file on gist and pasting a link here might help

Comment: Side note, just in case you didn't know -- you don't have to use separate ports for different sites hosted on the same system -- you can set the website name in the virtual configuration, and have them both use port 80.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have each in its own file in /etc/apache2/sites-available and a symbolic link to  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ ?

site1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /dir/dir/
    ServerName site1.domain.com
    <Directory /dir/dir/>
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/dir/dir/cgi-bin">
    </Directory> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /dir/dir/cgi-bin/
</VirtualHost>
```

site2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot /dir/dir/
    ServerName site2.domain.com
    <Directory /dir/dir/>
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/dir/dir/cgi-bin">
    </Directory> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /dir/dir/cgi-bin/
</VirtualHost>
```